# PHP reversing a byte and printing it

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding, bit, non-ascii-characters

I'm working with strings in PHP and the character 'a' in binary looks like this: **01100001**.

What I want to do is reverse this, which then becomes **10000110** and convert back to its text representation, but everytime I try it either gives me a ? or a blank square indicating a non-printable or invalid character.

I tried online ASCII/UNICODE binary to text converters but they all give me nothing, why is that and how could I see what character does my byte decode to?

Comment: Just bad luck - a lot of the characters with the high bit set, come out at various special characters (they are over 128 decimal).  If you tried something like `b` it should give you something.  Just found https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-a-uppercase-ascii-code-65.html which shows more results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10000110` is decimal `134` which means it's in the *extended* ASCII table (value over 127)

To be displayed properly it should be converted to `cp1252`

```
<?php
for ($i = 33; $i <= 255; $i++) {
    echo "$i: " . htmlentities(chr($i), ENT_QUOTES, 'cp1252') . "<br />";
}
```

[See also here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/converting-extended-ascii-characters-128-159-into-html-entities/6013/2)

Comment: it works partially but some characters still remain with the question mark. Thank you anyway.